# The buying mechanic for a stock market simulator

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need help making my Python code easier to read. My friend and I are creating a stock market simulator. This is the function for the buying mechanic.

The purpose of this section is to simulate a buying process. If the user wants to buy a specific stock, they just type its name into the terminal. It then asks them the quantity How much they want to buy. Once the input is given, its total value is stored in a variable called 'SessionCost' by multiplying the choice by the stock value, in this case, it is SNAP. It then checks if the balance is more or less than `SessionCost`. If more, it subtracts the `SessionCost` variable from from the total balance, and then adds the quantity chosen to the  'OwnedSnap' variable.

```
if choice == '1':
    clear()
    print("What company would you like to invest in?")
    time.sleep(1)
    choice = input('Enter here: ')
    if choice == 'return':
      clear()
    elif choice == 'snap':
      if balance < SNAP:
        print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
        time.sleep(2)
        choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
        if choice == 'return':
          clear()
      else:
        choice = input('Enter buying quantity: ')
        choiceInt = int(choice)
        SessionCost = choiceInt * SNAP
        clear()
        if balance < SessionCost:
          print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
          choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
          if choice == 'return':
            clear()
        else:
          balance -= SessionCost
          OwnedSnap += choiceInt
          clear()
```

I had to copy and paste this code throughout 15 different stock choices, and it is impossible to work with and read if a sudden error would show up. I imagine I can use functions and classes to solve it myself but I am not too familiar with them and have bad experiences with them on other projects.

The fifteen stock choices are listed under `# investements`.

For the owned stocks, I just used 'ownedSnap' and replaced Snap with the stock name, and assigned all of their values to 0.

Full code:

```
# script.modules
import time 
from os import system
def clear():
  system("clear")
from colorama import Fore
import random


balance = 500

# investments
SNAP = 84.55
AAPL = 145.76
TWTR = 62.25
TSLA = 759.05
NFLX = 587.55
FB = 363.05
MSFT = 299.50
DIS = 182.87
GPRO = 9.50
SUBX = 113.41
F = 13.49
BABA = 160.00
BAC = 40.40
GE = 100.30
GOOGL = 2811.00

#Owned
OwnedSnap = 0
OwnedAapl = 0
OwnedTwtr = 0
OwnedTsla = 0
OwnedNflx = 0
OwnedFb = 0
OwnedMsft = 0
OwnedDis = 0
OwnedGpro = 0
OwnedSubx = 0
OwnedF = 0
OwnedBaba = 0
OwnedBac = 0
OwnedGe = 0
OwnedGoogl = 0
# script.start
print("Loading dashboard..")
time.sleep(2)
clear()

while True:
  print(Fore.GREEN,"Stock Simulator\nby William & Bryson")
  print("")
  print(Fore.WHITE,"1 -> Invest\n 2 -> Stock Options\n 3 -> Sell\n 4 -> Owned Stock\n 5 -> About\n 6 -> current balance")
  choice = input("> ")


  if choice == "options":
    clear()
    print("Option:\n'invest NAME 00' - invests in choosen company.\n'bank' - opens BOS dashboard. ")

    choice = input("\nType return to go back > ")
    if choice == 'return' or '> ':
      clear()

  pass

  if choice == '1':
    clear()
    print("What company would you like to invest in?")
    time.sleep(1)
    choice = input('Enter here: ')
    if choice == 'return':
      clear()
    elif choice == 'snap':
      if balance < SNAP:
        print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
        time.sleep(1)
        choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
        if choice == 'return':
          clear()
      else:
        choice = input('Enter buying quantity: ')
        choiceInt = int(choice)
        SessionCost = choiceInt * SNAP
        clear()
        if balance < SessionCost:
          print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
          choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
          if choice == 'return':
            clear()
        else:
          balance -= SessionCost
          OwnedSnap += choiceInt
          clear()

        clear()
    elif choice == 'aapl':
      if balance < AAPL:
        print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
      else:
        choice = input('Enter buying quantity: ')
        choiceInt = int(choice)
        SessionCost = choiceInt * AAPL
        if balance < SessionCost:
          print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
          choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
          if choice == 'return':
            clear()
        else:
          balance -= SessionCost
          OwnedAapl += choiceInt
          print(f'You bought {choice} items. your remaining balance is {balance}')
          clear()

          

    elif choice == 'twtr':
      if balance < TWTR:
        print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
      else:
        choice = input('Enter buying quantity: ')
        choiceInt = int(choice)
        SessionCost = choiceInt * TWTR
        if balance < SessionCost:
          print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
          choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
          if choice == 'return':
            clear()
        else:
          balance -= SessionCost
          OwnedTwtr += choiceInt
          print(f'You bought {choice} items. your remaining balance is {balance}')
          clear()
          
    elif choice == 'tsla':
      if balance < TSLA:
        print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
      else:
        choice = input('Enter buying quantity: ')
        choiceInt = int(choice)
        SessionCost = choiceInt * TSLA
        if balance < SessionCost:
          print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
          choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
          if choice == 'return':
            clear()
        else:
          balance -= SessionCost
          OwnedTsla += choiceInt
          print(f'You bought {choice} items. your remaining balance is {balance}')
          clear()
    elif choice == 'nflx':
      if balance < NFLX:
        print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
      time.sleep(2)
      choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
      if choice == 'return':
        clear()
      else:
        choice = input('Enter buying quantity: ')
        choiceInt = int(choice)
        SessionCost = choiceInt * NFLX
        clear()
        if balance < SessionCost:
          print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
          choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
          if choice == 'return':
            clear()
        else:
          balance -= SessionCost
          OwnedNflx += choiceInt
          clear()
    elif choice == 'fb':
      if balance < FB:
        print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
      time.sleep(2)
      choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
      if choice == 'return':
        clear()
      else:
        choice = input('Enter buying quantity: ')
        choiceInt = int(choice)
        SessionCost = choiceInt * FB
        clear()
        if balance < SessionCost:
          print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
          choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
          if choice == 'return':
            clear()
        else:
          balance -= SessionCost
          OwnedFb += choiceInt
          clear()
    elif choice == 'msft':
      if balance < MSFT:
        print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
      time.sleep(2)
      choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
      if choice == 'return':
        clear()
      else:
        choice = input('Enter buying quantity: ')
        choiceInt = int(choice)
        SessionCost = choiceInt * MSFT
        clear()
        if balance < SessionCost:
          print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
          choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
          if choice == 'return':
            clear()
        else:
          balance -= SessionCost
          OwnedMsft += choiceInt
          clear()
    elif choice == 'dis':
      if balance < DIS:
        print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
      time.sleep(2)
      choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
      if choice == 'return':
        clear()
      else:
        choice = input('Enter buying quantity: ')
        choiceInt = int(choice)
        SessionCost = choiceInt * DIS
        clear()
        if balance < SessionCost:
          print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
          choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
          if choice == 'return':
            clear()
        else:
          balance -= SessionCost
          OwnedDis += choiceInt
          clear()
    elif choice == 'gpro':
      if balance < GPRO:
        print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
      time.sleep(2)
      choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
      if choice == 'return':
        clear()
      else:
        choice = input('Enter buying quantity: ')
        choiceInt = int(choice)
        SessionCost = choiceInt * GPRO
        clear()
        if balance < SessionCost:
          print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
          choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
          if choice == 'return':
            clear()
        else:
          balance -= SessionCost
          OwnedGpro += choiceInt
          clear()
    elif choice == 'subx':
      if balance < SUBX:
        print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
      time.sleep(2)
      choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
      if choice == 'return':
        clear()
      else:
        choice = input('Enter buying quantity: ')
        choiceInt = int(choice)
        SessionCost = choiceInt * SUBX
        clear()
        if balance < SessionCost:
          print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
          choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
          if choice == 'return':
            clear()
        else:
          balance -= SessionCost
          OwnedSubx += choiceInt
          clear()
    elif choice == 'f':
      if balance < F:
        print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
      time.sleep(2)
      choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
      if choice == 'return':
        clear()
      else:
        choice = input('Enter buying quantity: ')
        choiceInt = int(choice)
        SessionCost = choiceInt * F
        clear()
        if balance < SessionCost:
          print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
          choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
          if choice == 'return':
            clear()
        else:
          balance -= SessionCost
          OwnedF += choiceInt
          clear()
    elif choice == 'baba':
      if balance < BABA:
        print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
      time.sleep(2)
      choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
      if choice == 'return':
        clear()
      else:
        choice = input('Enter buying quantity: ')
        choiceInt = int(choice)
        SessionCost = choiceInt * BABA
        clear()
        if balance < SessionCost:
          print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
          choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
          if choice == 'return':
            clear()
        else:
          balance -= SessionCost
          OwnedBaba += choiceInt
          clear()
    elif choice == 'bac':
      if balance < BAC:
        print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
      time.sleep(2)
      choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
      if choice == 'return':
        clear()
      else:
        choice = input('Enter buying quantity: ')
        choiceInt = int(choice)
        SessionCost = choiceInt * BAC
        clear()
        if balance < SessionCost:
          print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
          choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
          if choice == 'return':
            clear()
        else:
          balance -= SessionCost
          OwnedBac += choiceInt
          clear()
    elif choice == 'ge':
      if balance < GE:
        print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
      time.sleep(2)
      choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
      if choice == 'return':
        clear()
      else:
        choice = input('Enter buying quantity: ')
        choiceInt = int(choice)
        SessionCost = choiceInt * GE
        clear()
        if balance < SessionCost:
          print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
          choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
          if choice == 'return':
            clear()
        else:
          balance -= SessionCost
          OwnedGe += choiceInt
          clear()
    elif choice == 'googl':
      if balance < GOOGL:
        print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
      time.sleep(2)
      choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
      if choice == 'return':
        clear()
      else:
        choice = input('Enter buying quantity: ')
        choiceInt = int(choice)
        SessionCost = choiceInt * GOOGL
        clear()
        if balance < SessionCost:
          print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
          choice = input('Type Return to go back > ')
          if choice == 'return':
            clear()
        else:
          balance -= SessionCost
          OwnedGoogl += choiceInt
          clear()
    else:
      print(Fore.RED, 'Invalid Entry > ')
      clear()
      
  pass

  if choice == '2':
    clear()
    print("Here is a list of stock options..")
    print(Fore.GREEN, f'SNAP = {SNAP}\n AAPL = {AAPL}\n TWTR = {TWTR}\n TSLA = {TSLA}\n NFLX = {NFLX}\n FB = {FB}\n MSFT = {MSFT}\n DIS = {DIS}\n GPRO = {GPRO}\n SUBX = {SUBX}\n F = {F}\n BABA = {BABA}\n BAC = {BAC}\n GE = {GE}\n GOOGL = {GOOGL}')

    choice = input("\nType Return to go back > ")
    if choice == 'return':
      clear()

  pass

  if choice == '3':
    clear()
    print("What stock would you like to sell? > ")
    print() # owned stock

    choice = input("> ")
    if choice == 'return':
      clear()


  pass

  if choice == '5':
    clear()
    print("Welcome to Stock Simulator")
    #print("")
    #print("")

    choice = input("\nType Return to go back > ")
    if choice == 'return':
      clear()
  
  pass

  if choice == '4':
    clear()
    print(f'Owned Stock:\n SNAP = {OwnedSnap}\n AAPL = {OwnedAapl}\n TWTR = {OwnedTwtr}\n TSLA = {OwnedTsla}\n NFLX = {OwnedNflx}\n FB = {OwnedFb}\n MSFT = {OwnedMsft}\n DIS = {OwnedDis}\n GPRO = {OwnedGpro}\n SUBX = {OwnedSubx}\n F = {OwnedF}\n BABA = {OwnedBaba}\n BAC = {OwnedBac}\n GE = {OwnedGe}\n GOOGL = {OwnedGoogl}')

    choice = input("\nType Return to go back > ")
    if choice == 'return':
      clear()
  
  pass

  if choice == '6':
    clear()
    print(f'Current Balance is {balance}')
    choice = input("\nType Return to go back > ")
    if choice == 'return':
      clear()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few major issues with your code:

### Your code is really very messy

- You are repeating a lot of code which can be wrapped in a function.

You can store all your prices and owned shares in a `dict` as follows:

```
prices = {
    'SNAP': 84.55,
    'AAPL': 145.76,
    'TWTR': 62.25,
    'TSLA': 759.05,
    'NFLX': 587.55,
    'FB': 363.05,
    'MSFT': 299.50,
    'DIS': 182.87,
    'GPRO': 9.50,
    'SUBX': 113.41,
    'F': 13.49,
    'BABA': 160.00,
    'BAC': 40.40,
    'GE': 100.30,
    'GOOGL': 2811.00,
}

#Owned
owned_stocks = {
    'SNAP': 0,
    'AAPL': 0,
    'TWTR': 0,
    'TSLA': 0,
    'NFLX': 0,
    'FB': 0,
    'MSFT': 0,
    'DIS': 0,
    'GPRO':0,
    'SUBX': 0,
    'F': 0,
    'BABA': 0,
    'BAC': 0,
    'GE': 0,
    'GOOGL': 0,
}
```

and you can make a function to buy the given stock -

```
def buy_stock(stock):
    global balance
    if balance < prices[stock]:
        print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        choice = input('Enter buying quantity: ')
        choiceInt = int(choice)
        SessionCost = choiceInt * prices[stock]
        if balance < SessionCost:
            print(Fore.RED, 'You do not have enough money to buy this ')
        else:
            print(Fore.GREEN, f'You have bought {choiceInt} {stock}.')
            balance -= SessionCost
            owned_stocks[stock] += choiceInt
```

Further more, I would suggest you to wrap it up in a `class` to avoid any type of messiness.

### Indentation

It's a convention in python to use 4 spaces as indentation and not 2.
You can refer to the [pep8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines.

### Cross Platform

Your function `clear()` won't work on Windows.
To make it work cross platform:

```
def clear():
    os.system('cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear')
```

Credit to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2084628/16246688)

### User Experience

You can be flexible with the inputs and informative with the outputs. I will leave this for you to do.

I don't see any other problems with your code. I would love to see the remaining parts of the project in action.

**Happy Coding!**